# How do I create concurrency::task from result?

Tags: c++, c++11, task, ppl

I want to create a new task that is already completed from the given result. My current workaround is:

```
return concurrency::task<T>([]{return result;});
```

Is there anything better?

The problem is with the following code:

```
concurrency::task<bool> foo()
{
    if (smth)
        // the result is 
        return (foo_other() && foo_other2()).then([](std::vector<bool> results) {...});

    //return false;
    return concurrency::task<bool>([]{return false;});
}
```

As you can see, my function is asynchronous and it depends on another asynchronous function. But sometimes I can exit the app e.g. if the async task was already done. In that case I need to return a *continuable* task which returns a specified result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `std::task` -- do you mean `std::packaged_task`?

Comment: Use a `promise` and call `set_value`?

Comment: I think he's talking about the Microsoft Parallel Pattern Library (PPL):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx but the std:: is confusing.

Comment: @Christophe I'm not sure at all, what the OP's talking about. The [tag:stl] was misleading already. The only relevant thing I'm able to find is [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) as mentioned.

Comment: @Toni Petrina, could you please clarify if its `std::packaged_task` or `concurrency::task` ?  Also, it could help if you'd give us the broader context of your code:  what do you intend to do ?  Why not simply use the available result without an additional task ?

Comment: @Christophe I edited my post, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @ToniPetrina much clearer now ! Is your work around meant for foo_other2() (because the `.then()` follower needs `result`) ?

Comment: @Christophe I am not sure I understand your question completely and I thought the question was rather clear. If you used C#, then you would be familiar with the `Task.FromResult` function that wraps object into a completed task. That is what I need: a completed task that returns the specified result.

Comment: @ToniPetrina I don't use C# at all, but my question is related to parallelism and not to language.  I'm asking because parallel tasks (and piping tasks with .then)  is meant to optimize **processing**. Simply re-reading an existing output that was just produced is not really adding value to such an optimisation.  I think your question points out a synchronisation issue (missing .get() or .wait() or whatever) so I tried to find out more.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a completed task as follows:

```
concurrency::task_from_result<bool>(false);
```